# Object variable initialization

Tags: javascript

I have such a simple code

```
var q = {
  p1: 'kv3',
  p2: 'http://google.com/' + this.p1
};

console.log(q.p2);
```

which I expect to output the `p2 + p1`, but for some reason the `p1` seems to be undefined when I `console.log`. Isn't `p1` initialized before `p2`?

What would be the correct code for this?

Comment: `this` is only set when you call a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `this` is does not suddenly refer to `q` inside of the object declaration:

```
var p1 = 'kv3';

var q = {
  p1: p1,
  p2: 'http://google.com/' + p1
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The object `q` is initialised all in one, so everything inside it is inaccessible until the whole thing is done initialising. Try this:

```
var q = {
    p1: 'kv3'
};
q.p2 = 'http://google.com/' + q.p1

console.log(q.p2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is an additional parameter that functions (except arrow ones) receive when they are called.

Therefore, that `this` does not refer to the object (it has not been created yet anyways).

But you can instantiate an anonymous function instead:

```
var q = new function() {
  this.p1 = 'kv3';
  this.p2 = 'http://google.com/' + this.p1;
};
```